# Can you use the correct form of the verb? Having (do) my work, I (go) to see him.

Tags: verb-forms

My basic confusion is that I can't understand which form of verb should I use to complete the sentence? I always confused in that.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Can you please edit your question to make it clearer what you want your sentence to mean? When it happened, whether it was happening for some time, and so on.

Comment: But I posted question as it is as given in my grammar book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having done my work, I went to see him.

It mean in simple form that I went to see him after I had done my work.